# Php Simple HTML DOM Parser - how to work with block repeats

Tags: php, parsing, dom, foreach, simple-html-dom

I have blocks of `<h2>` but without attributes. After that go blocks of `<p>` without attributes.

Structure of this looked like this:

```
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
```

I'm using Php Simple HTML DOM Parser. I want to get data from `<h2>` block, after that get all `<p>` to another `<h2>` and so on.

But all `<h2>` must be connected to `<p>` which go after them. I thought to use `key => value` (example `<h2> => <p>,<p>,...` and another `<h2>`) but I am not sure how to do this.

Also, I know about `next_sibling()`, but don't know how to use it in loop. I did 2 variables, 1st has all `<h2>`, 2nd has `<p>`. I thought it can be useful for my goal. Here is the code:

```
$test = file_get_html('url');
foreach($test->find('h2') as $test2) {
  echo $test2 . '<br>';
  foreach($test->find('p') as $test3) {
    echo $test3 .'<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Robin Mackenzie, thank you, that you edited my question.))

Answer (score 1):

It's not super clear what you're looking for but here's an idea to get you started:

```
foreach($html->find('h2') as $el){
  $h2 = $el;
  while($el = $el->next_sibling()){
    if('p' != $el->tag) break;
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer of my question here. I hope it can help somebody!)

```
 `foreach ($html->find('.div') as $div)
    {
        if(!$next=$div->next_sibling()) continue;
            if($next->tag==='h2')
            {
                $h2 =$next;
                echo $h2;

                while ($h2 = $h2->next_sibling())
                {
                    if(!$h2->tag=='p') break;
                    {
                        $p =$h2;
                        echo $p;  
                    }     
                }
                while ($h2 = $h2->next_sibling())
                {
                    if(!$h2->tag=='table') break;
                    {
                        $tab =$h2;
                        echo $tab;
                    }     
                }
                while ($h2 = $h2->next_sibling())
                {
                    if(!$h2->tag=='ul') break;
                    {
                        $ul =$h2;
                        echo $ul;
                    }     
                }
            }
            else continue;
    }`
```